# feets to inches with class to class type conversion

Tags: c++

i was making a c++ program with class to class type conversion and i wrote this code... the variable i is not being affected by type conversion
i tried taking it outside but i cant make it work...please help

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class feet
{
    int f;
    public:
    void inputfeet()
        {
            cin>>f;
        }
    get()
    {
        return (f);
    }
};
class inches
{
    int i;
    public:
    void inputinches()
        {
            cin>>i;
        }

        void operator - (feet x){
        i=i+((x.get())*12);
        }
        void show(){
    cout<<"inches"<<i;
        }
};

int main()
{
    feet foot;
    inches inch;
    foot.inputfeet();
    inch.inputinches();
    -inch;
    inch.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is going to be hard to help you if you dont provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)...

Comment: The `inches` class doesn't have an unary `-` operator. And the subtraction operator you have doesn't really behave as it should. I recommend you check out e.g. [this reference of canonical implementations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations) of operators, especially the section on [binary arithmetic operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Binary_arithmetic_operators). And of course think about how subtraction is used normally.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with adding `feet inches::asFeet()` and `inches feet::asInches()` member functions for conversion.  You need constructors where you pass the converted measurement to the new object.